# Hover over reputation in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I ask a question on Stack Overflow or in chat, there is likely something that I do not understand or haven't learned. The community response often guides me toward the better answers. In other words, the upvoting helps me find the best solution. Chat does not have up or downvoting. This is essentially the point of chat, to create an informal environment for dialogue. Now most people in chat have good intentions, but not everyone that tries to help may have the experience to solve my problem.

This is why I am proposing enhancing chat with hover-over reputation points, in the same manner as in comments. I believe this would help users discern what suggestions from chat should be explored over others. Currently, chat will display a user's reputation points, but only after the user has posted several times in a row. In a busier chat room, this may never happen for any given user.

There are links to the users profile so it is possible to find the user's reputation points, but having it display on-hover is much more accessible. Reputation points is a huge contributor to the community and the ability to more easily view it would be a big plus.

As hichris123 pointed out, this is already available. I would like to amend my request and ask that this feature be moved from the user card to the chat feed. It is not easy for us newbs to find this feature.

Does anyone else think this would be useful?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily tie someone's reputation on SO to their ability to answer the question.  Some people are not very active and prefer to lurk, while others are new members.  Looking at their reputation you are already applying a preconception to the quality of the answer rather than taking the quality of what they are actually saying :)

Comment: @intracept reputation is tied to how much SO trusts the user/what the user is saying. I would expect a user with higher rep to have a higher rate of accuracy, not because they have a better quality of answer, but because they have learned what is appropriate to suggest and what isn't.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm not sure I agree with it.  You still seem to be imposing the perception that someone's SO rep carries more weight than their real world experience.  But I won't argue the point any further :)

Answer (score 7):

Hover over a person's username on their usercard in chat, and you should see their reputation.

[image]

Comment: Well shoot, I absolutely did not notice that. I don't love that this is a two-step process. I'm surprised that it's located there.

Comment: @Jenn It is kind of in an awkward place. I knew that there was a way to do this, so when getting the picture I had to experiment and figure out what you had to do to get the reputation to show up. ;)

Comment: +1 for using the [SO Close Vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for your test. Do you join the event at 21:00 UTC?